# Multiple canvases - trying to send parameters to function via EventListener

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, onclick, event-listener

This program already works with onclick, but I know that using onclick on a html code is bad practice, and I'd be better off using Event listeners.

I'm facing issues with sending parameters to my function though. I understand it's much easier to do that when it's just one canvas, with something like 
document.getElementById("canvas1").addEventListener("click", func, false);
and then using this in the function, but what if there are more than one?

This is what I did before:

```
<canvas id="canvas1" width="100" height="100" onclick="boxClick(1)">
</canvas>  
<canvas id="canvas2" width="100" height="100" onclick="boxClick(2)">
</canvas>
<canvas id="canvas3" width="100" height="100" onclick="boxClick(3)">
</canvas>
```

There are 9 canvases like this (it's a tic tac toe game).
Then,

```
function boxClick(num) {
    numId = "canvas" + num; 
    box = document.getElementById(numId);
    ctx = box.getContext("2d");
}
```

Then I used that ctx to draw my shapes on the clicked canvas.

How do I achieve the same with an event Listener.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

In pure js you can implement is like this, getting the elements by class and then binding listener to all all on click event.currentTarget gives you the clicked element

```js
function boxClick(event) {
    console.log(event.currentTarget)
    ctx = event.currentTarget.getContext("2d");
    console.log(ctx);
}

var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("box");



for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
    classname[i].addEventListener('click', boxClick, false);
}
```

```css
.box{
border:1px solid #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas1" width="100" height="100" class="box">
</canvas>  
<canvas id="canvas2" width="100" height="100" class="box">
</canvas>
<canvas id="canvas3" width="100" height="100" class="box">
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass 'this' and then you can refer that element

```js
function boxClick(element){
  alert(element.id)
}
```

```css
canvas{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas1" onClick="boxClick(this)"></canvas>  
<canvas id="canvas2" onClick="boxClick(this)"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas3" onClick="boxClick(this)"></canvas>
```

Or you can bind event listener to all the canvas like this.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')

for (var i = 0; i < canvas.length; i++) {
  canvas[i].addEventListener("click",box);
}

function box(){
  alert(this.id)
}
```

```css
canvas{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas1" ></canvas>  
<canvas id="canvas2" ></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas3" ></canvas>
```